# Border color is not changed when click in css pseudo class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to change input field border color when use click on it. I want to do it with CSS. So I use pseudo class focus for it. But here are some problem. It works only on select elements not on the element like input type text.

```css
.input-field {
  height: 3em;
  width: 80%;
  padding: .3rem 2rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 1px solid var(--input-field-color);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.input-group-append {
  margin-left: -40px !important;
}

.input-group-text {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: 0px !important;
}

.signUpButton {
  height: 3em;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  outline: none;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #EC008C 0%, #FC6767 100%);
  border: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input-field:focus {
  border-color: var(--input-field-focus-color) !important;
  transition: border-color .20s ease-in;
}

.input-field:active {
  border-color: var(--input-field-focus-color) !important;
  transition: border-color .20s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-header">
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="john">
  </div>
  <div class="form-header">
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="abc@example.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-header">
    <select class="input-field" name="gender">
      <option value="male"> Male</option>
      <option value="female"> Female</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-header">
    <select name="country" class="input-field">
      <option> India </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-header">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="#########" />
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fas fa-lock"> </i> </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-header">
    <input type="submit" class="signUpButton" name="submit" />
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: try changing the outline property

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue here it; it works perfectly fine for me when I run your code example.

Comment: `body{--input-field-color:#000000; --input-field-focus-color:#00cc00;}` add some color to varabales. it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Add some color to css variables
like this

```
  --input-field-color:#ccc;
  --input-field-focus-color:#00cc00;
```

Are you something like this.

```css
body{
  --input-field-color:#ccc;
  --input-field-focus-color:#00cc00;
}
.input-field {
  height: 3em;
  width: 80%;
  padding: .3rem 2rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 1px solid var(--input-field-color);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.input-group-append {
  margin-left: -40px !important;
}

.input-group-text {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: 0px !important;
}

.signUpButton {
  height: 3em;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  outline: none;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #EC008C 0%, #FC6767 100%);
  border: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input-field:focus,.input-field:active{
  border-color: var(--input-field-focus-color) !important;
  transition: border-color .20s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-header">
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="john">
  </div>
  <div class="form-header">
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="abc@example.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-header">
    <select class="input-field" name="gender">
      <option value="male"> Male</option>
      <option value="female"> Female</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-header">
    <select name="country" class="input-field">
      <option> India </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-header">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="#########" />
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fas fa-lock"> </i> </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-header">
    <input type="submit" class="signUpButton" name="submit" />
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: if you look at the output of your code. it has still same problem. border color change on select element on the other input field like name input filed

Comment: is are you want to change border color when selected any field to change all ? What is actually want?

Comment: yes i want to change border color of all input field on click